# The equivalent of eval() in python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7

We can use `eval(input())` to allow the user to enter a list in python3
Here is an example:

```
  L = eval(input('Enter a list: '))
  print('The first element is ', L[0])
  Enter a list: [5,7,9]
  The first element is 5
```

But `eval()` not working in python2.7

I want to input data as a list `[5,7,9]`
and want to take each value as `L[0]` is `5`, `L[1]` is `7`, etc. using python 2.7.

Answer (score 7):

[`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in Python 2 **already** applies `eval()`.

Python 3 `input()` is Python 2's [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), renamed. In Python 2, `input()` is the same thing as `eval(raw_input())`:

```
L = input('Enter a list: ')  # includes a call to `eval()` in Python 2
```

However, the better alternative is to use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead; it only allows Python literals, while `eval()` allows *arbitrary* Python expressions. For taking a list input with numbers, `ast.literal_eval()` is plenty and not open to security issues:

```
from ast import literal_eval

L = literal_eval(raw_input('Enter a list: '))  # safe alternative to eval
```

Note that you still need to pass in valid Python literals; use `['a', 4, 7]`, *not* `[a, 4, 7]`; *just* `a` without quotes is not a valid Python string literal.

Comment: Aliens landing on earth today would find it astonishing that Python 2 stops you adding up strings with `sum` solely because it's inefficient, recommending `''.join()` instead, but is perfectly happy for you to use `input()` without a word about `raw_input()` and `ast.literal_eval()` being safer. Backward compatibility is a harsh master.

Comment: it gave me ValueError:malformed string can you help me why it said so

Comment: @user2851022: because `a` is not a valid Python string literal; use quotes around strings.

Answer (score 0):

Martijn's correct re: `raw_input`/`input` - but it's worth noting the  approach that should be preferred on both for your example for safer evaluation of simple literals:

```
from ast import literal_eval
L = literal_eval(raw_input('Enter a list: ')) # or `input` for Python 3.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use  `input` in python 2.7.5

```
lst = input("Enter a list:")  
>> [1,2,3]  # lst = [1,2,3]

lst[0]  # 5
lst[1]  # 7
...
```

Comment: print(lst[0]) gives [ as answer why?

Comment: while i am entering characters in list like[a,4,7] it give me a NameError:name a is not defined

Comment: @user2851022: because `eval()` will see `a` as a variable name, one you didn't define in your code. Use `'a'` if you want to pass in a string value.